# ¿Cómo reemplazo el valor de una lista que se encuentra dentro de otra en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy atascado con una práctica de POO en Python (soy principiante). El ejercicio consiste en crear un programa de consola para agregar, modificar y eliminar autos que el usuario vaya digitado. He logrado hacer la primera (agregar) y la tercera (eliminar), pero estoy atascado en la segunda.

El problema en sí es que no logro encontrar una forma de reemplazar el valor del auto por el que introduzca el usuario, ya que he intentado con los métodos `.insert()` y `.remove()`, pero no consigo que hagan lo antes mencionado.

Dejo el código para que entiendan mejor:

```
class Coche:
    color = ""
    marca = ""
    modelo = ""
    velocidad = 0
    caballaje = 0
    puertas = 0

    lista_coches = []

    menu  = -1
    while menu < 1:
        options  = int(input("Menu de Coches\n1) Registrar Coches\n2) Modificar Coche\n3) Eliminar Coche\n4) Finalizar\n"))

        if options == 1:
            num_coches = int(input("Digita la cantidad de coches que quieres crear: "))

            for coche in range(num_coches):
                marca = input("Digita la marca del coche: ")
                modelo = input("Digita el modelo del coche: ")
                color_coche = input("Digita el color del coche: ")
                print("")

                coche = [marca, modelo, color_coche]
                lista_coches.append(coche)

                getTotal_Coches = len(lista_coches)
                if getTotal_Coches == num_coches:
                    print(f"Coches registrados:\n{lista_coches}\n")

        elif options == 2:
            print("Lista de Coches:")
            for coche in lista_coches:
                print(f"{lista_coches.index(coche)}.{coche}")
                
            id = int(input("Digita el ID del auto que quieres modificar: "))
            select_pieza = input("Digita el nombre de la pieza a modificar: ")
            
            if select_pieza == "marca":
                new_marca = input("Introduce el nombre de la nueva marca para el auto: ")
                lista_coches.insert(lista_coches[id:0],new_marca)
                print(lista_coches)

        elif options == 3:
            print("Lista de Coches:")
            for coche in lista_coches:
                print(f"{lista_coches.index(coche)}.{coche}")
                
            indice = int(input("Digita el ID del coche que quieres eliminar: "))
            lista_coches.pop(indice)
            print(f"\nCoche eliminado exitosamente.\n\nLista de Coches actual:\n{lista_coches}\n")

        elif options == 4:
            print("Programa finalizado.")
            break
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda o solución a este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
lista_coches[id][0]=new_marca
```

en lugar de:

```
lista_coches.insert(lista_coches[id:0],new_marca)
```

Comment: Sería preferible que dieras una breve explicación de tu respuesta para que fuese más completa

Comment: La marca va en la segunda posición de la lista. Lo correcto sería `lista_coches[id][1]=new_marca`

Comment: La solución de @firefly me ha servido para cambiar la marca, y la sugerencia de CandidMoe también aplica, pero para el modelo. ¡Muchas gracias a todos por esta solución! ![Solución](https://prnt.sc/u2e2gr).